# Can not find module 'xlsx' in angular

Tags: angular, xlsx, js-xlsx, sheetjs

I want to import `xlsx`.

So, i install `xlsx` using `npm install xlsx`.

And import `xlsx` module. `import * as XLSX from 'xlsx';`

(Also I try `import { foo, bar } from 'xlsx';`)

And run this code with Angular cli. `ng serve`.

I use it.

```
Angular CLI: 1.6.1
Node: 6.11.3
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 2.4.10
... common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms, http
... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic

@angular/cli: 1.6.1
@angular/router: 3.4.10
@angular/tsc-wrapped: 0.5.2
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.36
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.22
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.34
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.9.1
@schematics/angular: 0.1.11
@schematics/schematics: 0.0.11
typescript: 2.0.10
webpack: 3.10.0
```

please help. thanks.

Comment: What is the issue you are getting in the console?

Comment: Error message is this ==> TS2307:Cannot find module 'xlsx'

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way to add 3 party library which does not support import or ES6 functionality. Instead, you can add xlsx library in angular-cli.json file under script tag.

```
 // replace it with xlsx library
 "scripts": [
    "../node_modules/lodash/lodash.min.js"
  ],
```

And then in your component add below snippet and use it.

```
 import * as xlsx from "xlsx";
```

Comment: I have no way to use import? not declare

Comment: What do you mean by "replace it with xlsx library"?

Comment: There are lot of library available for xlsx, if you are using such library which does not support TS, you can include those JS files in script tag and use as a global object